# Remove Span tag from variable product woocommerce Analytical data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[Check Image <span -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cya1C.jpg) When I am looking at Analytical data, I often make an export for my shipping party, but I have to manually remove the span tag every time... Is there a solution for this?

I tries this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
// Or also
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
function remove_span_tags_from_product_name( $downloads ){
    // Only on my account downloads section
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('downloads') )
        return $downloads;

    // Loop though downloads
    foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
        // remove "span" html tags
        $downloads[$key]['product_name'] = str_replace( array('<span>', '</span>'), array('', ''), $download['product_name'] );
    }
    return $downloads;
}
```

It didnt work for me